# How to redraw a layout using canvas and matrix in android?

Tags: android, animation, layout

I want to  move and scale the view on the right while dragging it to left side.I tried to set the layout parameters  of this view on touch.It moved and scaled the view.But rendering is not correct when moving our finger fastly to both left and right sides.

This view on the right side is a custom layout extends `LinearLayout` having a `ListView` as child.And the left side is also another layout and integrated both layouts into a `Framelayout`(similar to slidingmenu).

Is there any way to render the layout (move and scale) the view without updating `LayoutParams`?

Is it possible to update the layout using canvas and matrix?

Here is the code for custom layout for view on the right side(the small view).

```
public class SlidingLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static String LOG_TAG = "SlidingLayout";

    private boolean isTranformed = false;

    private PanGestureListener gestureListener;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private boolean isAnimating = false;

    private boolean isScrolling = false;

    private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    private float posX = 0;
    private float posY = 0;

    public CustomSlidingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        gestureListener = new PanGestureListener();
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener);
        matrix.setTranslate(0, 0);
        matrix.setScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.save();
        /*canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.translate(posX, posY);
        super.onDraw(canvas);*/
        /*canvas.restore();
        matrix.reset();
        matrix = canvas.getMatrix();*/
        /*if (isTranformed) {
            matrix.postTranslate(posX, posY);
            canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);*/
    }

    private void makeViewSmall() {
        if (!isAnimating) {
            isAnimating = true;
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
            ResizeMoveAnimation anim = new ResizeMoveAnimation(this,
                    (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.8), displayMetrics.heightPixels / 4,
                    displayMetrics.widthPixels * 2, rect.bottom - displayMetrics.heightPixels
                            / 4);
            anim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
            startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }

    public void makeViewOriginal() {
        if(isTranformed){
            if (!isAnimating) {
                isAnimating = true;
                ResizeMoveAnimation anim = new ResizeMoveAnimation(this, 0, 0,
                        displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
                anim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
                anim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                anim.setDuration(1000);
                startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }else{
            makeViewSmall();
        }

    }

    private AnimationListener animationListener = new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) CustomSlidingLayout.this .getLayoutParams();
            if (isTranformed) {
                isTranformed = false;
                params.leftMargin = 0;
                params.topMargin =  0;
                params.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
                params.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                requestLayout();

            } else {
                isTranformed = true;
            }
            isAnimating = false;
        }
    };

    class PanGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
            if (isTranformed) {
                makeViewOriginal();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isTranformed) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private int _xDelta = 0;
    private int _yDelta = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (isTranformed) {
            final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                this.requestLayout();
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this .getLayoutParams();
                if (layoutParams.leftMargin == 0 && layoutParams.topMargin == 0) {
                    //this.requestLayout();
                    isTranformed = false;
                    isScrolling = false;
                    break;
                }
                isScrolling = true;
                int xDiff = layoutParams.leftMargin - (X - _xDelta);
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                int scaleFactor =  layoutParams.leftMargin > 0 ? layoutParams.leftMargin : 1;
                layoutParams.topMargin = layoutParams.topMargin - ((layoutParams.topMargin / scaleFactor) * xDiff);

                if (layoutParams.leftMargin < 0) {
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                }
                if (layoutParams.topMargin < 0) {
                    layoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                }
                layoutParams.width = (displayMetrics.widthPixels - layoutParams.leftMargin);
                layoutParams.height = (displayMetrics.heightPixels - (layoutParams.topMargin * 2));
                this.requestLayout();

                /*final float dx = X - _xDelta;
                final float dy = Y - _yDelta;
                posX += dx;
                posY += dy;
                //matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor,0.0f,0.5f);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)(displayMetrics.widthPixels - posX), (int)(displayMetrics.heightPixels - posY), Config.RGB_565);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                matrix.postTranslate(posX, posY);
                canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
                this.draw(canvas);
                _xDelta = X;
                _yDelta = Y;
                invalidate();*/
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                isScrolling = false;

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this
                        .getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = X - lParams.topMargin;
                posX  = 0;
                posY = 0;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When is the time you want to update your layout?

Comment: I specified it in the Question.I want to update the view while dragging(on touch move).

Comment: put SlidingLayout.this.invalidate() after break;

Comment: if you invalidate you should draw in your ondraw method

Comment: But it flashes while moving and draw more than one view if we move our finger fast in both directions.That is my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can call `invalidate()` in `onTouch()` to execute the code in `onDraw()` to redraw the view.

invalidate() will force a view to draw.

Comment: But it flashes while moving and draw more than one view if we move our finger fast in both directions.That is my issue

Comment: Then you can try, a view inside a relativelayout and changing position of thet view in ontouch().

Comment: So in that case, i think i wont flash. I am not sure, is this your case. But from my understanding i am suggesting you this.